# Book about a girl named Abygail who can travel in time

Tags: identification-request

Does anyone know of a book that satisfies the following properties:

- The book is about a girl named Abygail/Abigail (or possibly another variation of this name).
- The book says that the name "Abygail" is an old witch name.
- The book was published in 2004 or earlier
- The book was written or translated to English (possibly by an English author during the 1990s)
- Abygail can wield magic and travel in time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing Beatie Bow by Ruth Park

Worldcat.org [abstract](https://www.worldcat.org/title/playing-beatie-bow/oclc/978692594):

> Disturbed that her mother could welcome back her unfaithful father,
> Abigail Kirk undergoes a mysterious voyage to nineteenth-century
> Australia, where her experiences help her to understand the power of
> love and to accept her father.

The character born Lynette changes her name to Abigail:

> 'Tell me some witches' names, Mum,' she said.
> 'Well, there's Samantha, and Tabitha,' Kathy began.
> 'Oh, I don't want soppy TV names,' said her daughter. 'Some real witches' names.
> 'They'd have to be old ones,' said Kathy thoughtfully, like Hephzibah, or Susannah, or Petronella, or Abigail.
> 'That's the one!' cried the girl.
> 'But it's so plain, so knobbly, so... so awful!' wailed Kathy.
> Grandmother smiled. Abigail could see quite easily that Grandmother thought she was plain and knobbly and awful, too. So that settled it.